# How to click on button using ruby+watir+selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

Hi i'm using ruby+watir+selenium to automate a login page.
so the html section for button is:

```
<paper-button id="ok" class="style-scope login-window x-scope paper-button-0" role="button" tabindex="0" animated="" aria-disabled="false" elevation="0">OK</paper-button>
```

my code is:

```
@browser.text_field(:xpath => ("(//input[@id='input'])[2]")).send_keys('user')
@browser.text_field(:xpath => ("(//input[@id='input'])[3]")).send_keys('pass')
sleep 10
@browser.button(:id => ("ok")).click
```

and i tried this:

```
@browser.button(:class => 'style-scope login-window x-scope paper-button-0').click

@browser.button(:id => 'ok').click
```

These return:

```
C:\Komodo_files>ruby test.rb
Loaded suite test
Started
E
====================================================================================================

Error: test_login(login): Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: element located, but timed
 out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::TextField: located: true; {:xpath=>"(//input[@id='input'
])[2]", :tag_name=>"input"}> to be present
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:622:in `raise_present'
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:662:in `rescue in eleme
nt_call'
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:673:in `element_call'
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:283:in `send_keys'
test.rb:27:in `test_login'
     24: def test_login
     25: @browser.goto "http://qa.application.com"
     26: sleep 20
  => 27: @browser.text_field(:xpath => ("(//input[@id='input'])[2]")).send_keys('user'
)
     28: @browser.text_field(:xpath => ("(//input[@id='input'])[3]")).send_keys('pass')
     29: sleep 10
     30: @browser.button(:id => ("ok")).click
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: The exception is actually saying that Watir is failing to input the text field - ie it's failing before the button click. It says the text field is not visible. Are you sure it's visible? Is there a user action that needs to occur to make it visible?

Comment: ok if i remove the line for button the test passes without errors.

Comment: That doesn't seem to add up. Given that removing the button prevents the error from occurring, are you sure you pasted the right error message?

Comment: if i remove the line with button then the message at the end of the test says C:\Komodo_files>ruby test.rb
Loaded suite test
Started
.

Finished in 39.17224 seconds.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
100% passed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

0.03 tests/s, 0.00 assertions/s

C:\Komodo_files>

Comment: it looks i have a problem with timing

Comment: @kirkdouglas Your text field is invisible, So the failure and your button click has nothing to do with that because your text_field entry happens before the button click.

Comment: wow, I just noticed you have multiple elements on the page with the same ID value (if your code is correct)..  That violates the HTML specs, and technicaly means the page is invalid HTML.  (although most browsers won't care)   Why do developers do that? or use frameworks that do that.   it's really annoying and makes the sites much harder to test.